# OpenJDK continues running after closing Android emulator

Tags: java, android, flutter, visual-studio-code

### Problem

I am using VS Code to edit and run Android projects.  The emulator will open and I see the program `OpenJDK Platform binary` start, followed by the program compiling and running.  However, after closing the Android emulator and VS Code, OpenJDK continues to run.

[image: Task Manager screenshot]
*(Task manager after closing Emulator/VSC)*

### Solution?

Is this normal behavior?  Is there a way to have OpenJDK JRE shut down after the emulator/VSC exits?

My main concern is battery life as I am using a laptop.

### Extra Information

**System:** Windows 10 Pro (1909)
**Visual Studio Code version:** 1.42.0

#### Notes

- I am using the Flutter framework for Android development
- Intel Optane memory is enabled
- The emulator & JRE being used are from the Android Studio bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JVM Process Status Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) helped me identify why OpenJDK was not closing. Running `[path_to_jre]/bin/jps -l` in terminal spat out the following:

```
2272 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon
4500 sun.tools.jps.Jps
```

#### The solution I landed on is to create a task in VSCode:

```
...
    {
      "label": "gradle --stop",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "C:\\Gradle\\gradle-6.1.1\\bin\\gradle --stop",
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": true,
        "clear": false
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
...
```

This results in the OpenJDK process ending.

Answer (score 0):

1* open the task manager, and locate the process ID

2*

```
TASKKILL /PID %PID%
```

Comment: I could use a script to kill the process.  By _why_ does it not close automatically once not being used?